# Mysql LEFT JOIN: Limit parent table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get results from DB, but limit the results to the right

```
SELECT posts.text, comments.text 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.postid= post.id 
Limit 0,5
```

The above will return 5 comments of the first post if there is five comments. However I want to return ALL comments, but stop the query after 5 posts. How do I go about this?

---

Sorry my question was a bit unclear at the start as I wrote the LEFT JOIN wrong..

This is the solution to my problem:

```
SELECT posts.text, comments.text 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM posts Limit 0,5 ) 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.postid= post.id
```

One other question. I have only specified posts.text as a select column but will all columns now be returned as "*" is included in the sub query?

Comment: I'm confused. Can a post only have one comment, or should that be `post.id=comment.postId`?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right, I've amended that

Answer (score 7):

if that's what you want, use a subquery to get only 5 parents.

```
SELECT  p.text PostText,
        c.text CommentText
FROM
        (
            SELECT  id, text
            FROM    posts
            LIMIT   5
        ) p
        LEFT JOIN comments c
            ON c.postId  = p.id;
```

Comment: In my experience subqueries in MySQL can be much slower than expected

Comment: @cja there are always exceptions. but how can you solve this if not using subquery?

Comment: @cja It's not a correlated subquery, so it's only executed once. Performance should be fine, although I suspect the question is a bit confused about the actual table relations.

Comment: This will not work if you have an `ORDER BY`. It will order only in the result of the subquery. If you want to order by latest comments.